# No signal red light on green light flashes 4 times

Tags: pi-4, boot-issues

Some please talk to me like Im an idiot and explain how I can fix my sons computer.

Power on, red light on - green light flashes four times.

It was working ... now no signal and issues.

I have no idea

Comment: Read the "is your pi not booting" sticky over at raspberrypi.org - https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=1485558#p1485558

Comment: This is likely caused by a faulty (or missing) SD Card. See [Pi4 Boot Problems Sticky](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151&sid=ec118b286843110a1175ec84a250a7dc#p1485558)

Comment: An easy way to tell that is to see what it (the green LED) does when plugged in without an SD card.  I doubt it will flash 4 times -- it will either stay on or stay off.  The probable cause is corruption of the boot partition caused by an improper shutdown: As with any computer, the OS  must be shut down before the power is cut.  Unlike a normal computer, it does not have a button to facilitate this with one push, so you must remember to properly halt the OS before you pull the plug or you may continue to have these kinds of problems.